# CSS Flexbox position:absolute Container doesn't show all Elements

Tags: css, flexbox

**Hey everyone**

my first Question on SO, so please be kind :)

I experience a Problem with a flexbox container and its children when overflow-y is needed. So if you change the width of the container that it's needed to scroll vertically, not all elements are visible anymore, you just can't scroll up enough.

Here is the codePen: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmWXeN)

html:

```
<div id="dailyplan-header">
  <button type="buttton">someButton</button>
  <button type="buttton">someButton2</button>
  <button type="buttton">someButton3</button>
</div>
<div id="dailyplan-container">
  <div class="dailyplan">Parent Name0
    <div>Some Element0</div>
    <div>Some Element1</div>
    <div>Some Element2</div>
    <div>Some Element3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyplan">Parent Name1
    <div>Some Element0</div>
    <div>Some Element1</div>
    <div>Some Element2</div>
    <div>Some Element3</div>
    <div>Some Element4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyplan">Parent Name2
    <div>Some Element0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyplan">Parent Name3
    <div>Some Element0</div>
    <div>Some Element1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyplan">Parent Name4
    <div>Some Element0</div>
    <div>Some Element1</div>
    <div>Some Element2</div>
    <div>Some Element3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyplan">Parent Name5
    <div>Some Element0</div>
    <div>Some Element1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyplan">Parent Name6
    <div>Some Element0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyplan">Parent Name7
    <div>Some Element0</div>
    <div>Some Element1</div>
    <div>Some Element2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body {
  background-color:#fff;
}

#dailyplan-header {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f0ad4e;
}

#dailyplan-container {
  position:absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top:50px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.dailyplan {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: green;
  min-width:250px;
  padding:20px;
  margin:10px;
  border-radius: 7px 20px 7px 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px 20px 7px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px 20px 7px 20px;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
}
```

You can see there, when shrinking the Viewport to a small Width (smartphone) not all children elements are visible anymore. In particular you cannot scroll "up" until the first child is displayed.

Of course I tried to search for a Solution but either I don't have the right search terms or there just isn't a matching Answer. Any hints to improve this description, that others could find it better, are of course appreciated.

Comment: Hi naoko, Kindly, please read [ask]. It's not that hard and not that long. Your question is not constructed as it should, and it greatly helps the people trying to help you, and future readers if you do construct it properly.

Comment: Hey Amit, someone already improved my Post to include the CSS, thx to him. Sorry before I understood what happened I didn't noticed who the Person was. I also added some Description before the Link to Codepen. So it this FAQ-conform now or do I need to add some more?

Comment: It's better, but not "good". A good question would have a MCVE. That is a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, and in the case of HTML it would be inlined as a snippet. That way, the entire relevant information is right infornt of us, it's "playable", and it's super easy to copy into an answer for modification.

Comment: ok, I added the relevant html parts too. I was assuming a CodePen is enough, but I guess it makes sense because who knows how long the Pen will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the position correctly for the flex.

```
#dailyplan-container {
 position:relative;  /*--Set the position relative instead of Absolute--*/
 box-sizing: border-box;
 top:50px;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 align-items: stretch;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-content: center;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

Check this fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zb6f0t7g/)

Do comeback if you still have the issue.!

Comment: Hey CodeRomeos, thx for you answer. In deed this solves the scrolling Issue but introduces new Issues. I was using position:absolute to have a "sticky" header and that #dailyplan-header is using all remaining space -> both isn't working anymore with position:relative.

Comment: ok, nice I found a solution with your hint that does both. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epYJPg

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thx for the answers, the hint from CodeRomeos solved it though with getting the desired behavior with a different approach then before, but I guess that's fine :)

```
#dailyplan-header {
  position:fixed;/*<-- changed from absolute to fixed */
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f0ad4e;
  z-index:2; /*<-- now needed. */
}
#dailyplan-container {
  position:relative /*<-- changed as suggested. */
  height: 100%; /*<-- now needed. */
  ...
}
```

Thx for the unbelievable fast help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `position: absolute` on the container, you could also add an extra wrapper around your `dailyplan` elements.

Something like

```
<div id="dailyplan-container">
  <div class="dailyplan-wrapper">
    <div class="dailyplan">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then give this element a flexbox layout instead of the `#dailyplan-container` element.

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/grrtbrtr/pen/QjozrL